# Can't connect to a docker container with Janusgraph (Berkeleyje/Lucern) from docker container with gremlin console

Tags: docker, janusgraph, gremlin-server

**Goal:** I want to set up a graph database and ultimately access the data from a set of static traversals built into a Nodejs application

**Intermediate goal 1:** As a learning exercise, Instead of using a Nodejs application, I'm initially going to use gremlin-console in a docker container on my local machine.  - I'm using the docker container `tinkerpop/gremlin-console:latest`

**Intermediate goal 2:** Run Janusgraph (Berkeleyje/Lucern/gremlin-server) in a docker container on a VM on a remote server in my org (I don't want any cloudy suggestions please) - I'm using the docker container `janusgraph/janusgraph:latest` v3.4.4

**Revised Intermediate goal 2:** Because of the problems I've had connecting, run Janusgraph (Berkeleyje/Lucern/gremlin-server) in a docker container on my local machine, co-located  with the docker container that's running gremlin-console

---

**Steps:**

1. I pulled the server docker image with `docker pull janusgraph/janusgraph:latest`
2. I ran the image with `docker run -it -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph:latest /bin/bash` (also with imageID)
3. From the console in the running container `/opt/janusgraph/bin/gremlin-server.sh`

This returned: (snipped)

```
3321 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 serialization class is deprecated.
3370 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
3370 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 serialization class is deprecated.
3371 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo-stringd with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
3395 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
3395 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
3397 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0 serialization class is deprecated.
3398 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0
3400 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0 serialization class is deprecated.
3400 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo-lite with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0
3400 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0 serialization class is deprecated.
3401 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo-stringd with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0
3401 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0 serialization class is deprecated.
3405 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0
3405 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - application/json already has org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0 configured - it will not be replaced by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, change order of serialization configuration if this is not desired.
3410 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0
3411 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - application/json already has org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0 configured - it will not be replaced by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, change order of serialization configuration if this is not desired.
3458 [gremlin-server-boss-1] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Gremlin Server configured with worker thread pool of 1, gremlin pool of 8 and boss thread pool of 1.
3458 [gremlin-server-boss-1] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Channel started at port 8182.
```

I hoped the serialization class warnings were not significant

4. I pulled the console docker image with `docker pull tinkerpop/gremlin-console:latest`
5. I ran the image with `docker run -it -p 8182:8182 tinkerpop/gremlin-console:latest /bin/bash` (also with imageID)
6. (in the non-colocated version, I adjusted `/opt/gremlin-console/conf/remote.yaml` to point `host` at the server hostname - which was resolvable to its IP from the container)

```
hosts: [localhost] # OR [ the remote hostname ] as per the two versions of goal 2
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

7. From the console in the running container `/opt/janusgraph/bin/gremlin.sh`
8. From the gremlin console `remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml` which returned

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
```

9. From gremlin console `:remote console` (to toggle all subsequent commands to the remote gremlin-server)

**Problem**
It seemed like console was connecting to server but when I ran 
`gremlin> :> graph = TinkerGraph.open(conf/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-berkeleyje-server.properties)` it responded
`Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.` This is the same whether I'm trying to connect the co-located or remote gremlin-server

What to do now? Where to look? Why is Gremlin SO DIFFICULT!

**Meta problem**
I'm not clear (and the documentation doesn't explain) whether the `:> TinkerGraph.open(server.properties)` expects a path to the server `.properties` file local to the console or (more likely I think) a path relative to the remote server

I wish the docs took less for granted and (for what must be only a limited number of architectural patterns*) explained comprehensively and **seperately** everything that's required

*

- Server & client co-located on a machine, sharing resources/network &c.
- Server & client containerised on a machine, so how to get them to talk (through container isolation)
- Server on remote machine to client (with and without containerisation)

Comment: Forgot to mention that running `graph = TinkerGraph.open(conf/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-berkeleyje-server.properties)` elicits no response at the server end, making me doubt the success response of the previous `:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml` command

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick version that is working for me:

```
docker run --name janusgraph-default \
    -e janusgraph.storage.berkeleyje.cache-percentage=80 \
    -e gremlinserver.threadPoolWorker=2 \
    -e gremlinserver.channelizer=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WsAndHttpChannelizer \
    -p 8182:8182 \
    janusgraph/janusgraph:latest
```

I have a customized the channelizer here, which can be avoided if you only want websocket and not Http.

In the gremlin console:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
:remote console
graph
==>standardjanusgraph[berkeleyje:/var/lib/janusgraph/data]
```

- Make sure `remote.yaml` is pointing to localhost:8182 (port from the docker run command)
- The second line `remote console` is only to avoid `:>` for each command

I believe the server looks for the properties file in its relative path. The docker version copies the properties file to `/etc/opt/` as mentioned here: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker